# Custom painting not working as intended

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

I'm making a GUI application which finds and draws convex hull for a set of points.

Here's the frame:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{
Panel panel = new Panel();
JButton drawHull = new JButton("Draw Convex Hull");
Frame(String title) {
    super(title);
    // setLayout
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // add components to the frame
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(drawHull, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    // add actionListener for drawHull button
    drawHull.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panel.drawConvexHull();
        }
    }
    );
}
}
```

The frame contains a button (at the bottom of the frame) and a `Panel` object.

Here's the `Panel` class:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel{
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
public Panel() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            points.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
            repaint();
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if(!points.isEmpty()) {
        Point p = points.get(points.size()-1);
        g.fillOval(p.x-2, p.y-2, 4, 4);
    }
}
public void drawConvexHull() {
    // code for finding convex hull
}
}
```

I have added a `mouseListener` to the `Panel` class so that when the user clicks anywhere on the panel, a point is drawn.

When I run the code, everything looks fine. Here's a sample run.

[image]

**Now here's the problem:**

As soon as I click the panel, this happens

[image]

A button appears on the top of the frame. **Why is this happening?**

One more thing. When I click this button on the top, a point is drawn. Here, have a look:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Without calling `super.paintComponent(g)` in `paintComponent` the background is not repainted leading to unpredictable results on the panel component.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (Point point: points) {
        g.fillOval(point.x - 2, point.y - 2, 4, 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do something like: 
 `if(firstTime) {
super.paintCompoenent(g);
}`

The same thing happens

Comment: simply do `super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: Another way is by clearing the panel every time a point is added and use a for loop to draw all the points again. But I don't want to use this approach.

Comment: If I simply add `super.paintComponent(g)`, the previous points get erased. Only one point is displayed

Comment: doing it the way you suggest is messy & unpredictable on "dirty" painted panel. refresh the whole panel & paint all points